# angular 2 pass data betwen components through @viewchild

Tags: angular

hi guys I have a scenario like this.

I have a modal which I am doing an http.post request like this:

```
this.request.RequestMsg('POST', '/user', this.data).then(response => {
        this.userComponent.data.push(response.body)
    })
```

> this.userComponent.data.push(response.body) this code is a @viewChild

```
@ViewChild(UsersComponent) userComponent: UsersComponent
```

so all I want to do is, when the modal is being closed in the **UsersComponent**
I want to push the response.body into this.data{}, but I cannot.

All I want to achieve is when the modal is being saved I got a return 200 OK and I close the modal i want the **UsersComponent** to be reloaded so I have to get all the data from the server

how could I achieve this ?

Comment: Great examples in the official docs: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: I cannot achieve the browser reload :S

Comment: Which technique did you use to build your modal? is it custom code or something like ng-bootstrap?

Comment: yes it's ng-bootstrap from valor software